# Should I cook frozen salmon differently from fresh salmon?

Tags: fish, salmon, frozen

I bought some frozen wild-caught salmon fillets for the first time so see how we like it.  Can I broil it the way I usually cook salmon, or does the freezing process lend itself better to other methods, like sauteeing or poaching, or does it even matter?

Comment: Dear tangible3, our site has some strict rules. One of them is that we don't ask questions which have thousands of equally-good answers, such as "what dish can I prepare with ingredient X". Reading the body of your question, I see that you did not mean to ask that, but your old title was very easy to be interpreted this way, and I guess this is why somebody cast a close vote on your question.I edited the title in order to prevent such an interpretation and keep the question from getting closed; I hope it expresses your original intent well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Once you thaw the salmon, you can treat it like you would fresh salmon.  Freezing may degrade the texture of the fish a small amount (it may not even be noticeable if they were commercially frozen in a blast chiller), or allow a little moisture loss, but otherwise the fish is essentially unchanged.

If there is any weeping or moisture coming out, pat the filets dry with a lint free towel or paper towel before high heat cooking methods like broiling or pan frying.

If the filets are thin, you can even cook them from frozen without pre-thawing them; they will thaw as part of the cooking process.

The best way to thaw them is to put them in refrigerator until they are thawed.   You can then proceed with your recipe like you normally would.